# Microsoft Visual Studio Objects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, c#

Hello is it possible to create an object that would function like a button?

Because I'm making a room management system for a hotel and the manager wants me to put a graphical representation of the rooms. I'm thinking it would be user friendly if I create an object that would represent the room e.g (rectangle) because I think it's too awful if I put many buttons in it. (it's too painful in the eyes).

The object should be clickable because when the user clicks or double clicks it. The room details would appear.

Thank you very much...

Comment: Are you working on a Windows Form, a WPF application or something else?

Comment: Use the MouseDown event.  You'll have to add the code that figures out exactly what room was clicked from the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. All of the controls (as long as they inherit from [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx), which basically all UI elements do) have a [`Click`-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx), which you can register to so you get notified when it is clicked.

If you tell me if you are using WinForms or WPF I can give you an example of drawing a custom clickabel object.

Answer (score 0):

You can either just set the size of a button to represent the room, or you can catch the `Click` event of any element you like to use to represent the room, for example a `Panel`.

You can also create a class that inherits from a control and implements some more features, that way it's easy to reuse it. Example:

```
public class Room : Panel {

  // perhaps something to keep track of what room it is
  private int _id;

  // a constructor that sets the data that you need
  public Room(int id) {
    _id = id;
  }

  protected override OnClick(EventArgs e) {
    // here you can handle the click
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an object that would inherit from `Control`, and do custom drawing code using `System.Drawing`, It's a pretty simple task. With `Control` you're exposed to regular events like `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, `OnPaint`, `PaintBackground`. These are events you're going to want if you add effects.